# Ubuntu with ZFS on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi, zfs

In the spirit of setting up a very cheap and low-power remote backup of a ZFS pool on my Ubuntu based NAS, I am considering Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB with two external 12TB 3.5’’ USB disks in a mirror vdev.

Performance is not an issue, as the device will have one job only: replicate my datasets in a remote location.

Hence the following questions:

1. Is installing and running ZFS in Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 4 as trivial a on an x86 machine?
2. What would the steps be to get it up and running?
3. How could the configuration of ZFS be optimized (e.g. disabling of the cache) in order to succeed on this kind of hardware?